# square root of a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory

Hello,
I'd like to know the square root of the following $n$ by $n$ matrix, for $n > 2$ and $r>0$:

$R_{ii}=r+1$ for $i < n$

$R_{ij}=r$ otherwise

The $2$ by $2$ case is given by

$\sqrt{R}=\frac{1}{d} \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1+r+\sqrt{r} & r \\\ r & r+\sqrt{r}\end{array}\right]$

where $d=\sqrt{1+2r+2\sqrt{r}}$.

Any thoughts?
Many thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your matrix has minimal polynomial $(R-1)(R^2-(nr+1)R+r)=0$. From there it is easy to get its spectral form $E_1+\lambda_+E_++\lambda_-E_-$ where $\lambda_\pm=\frac12\left(nr+1\pm\sqrt{(nr+1)^2-4r}\right)$, and from there the square root $E_1+\sqrt{\lambda_+}E_++\sqrt{\lambda_-}E_-$.

Comment: Here the eigenprojectors are, explicitly:
$$E_1=\frac{R-\lambda_+}{1-\lambda_+}\frac{R-\lambda_-}{1-\lambda_-}$$
$$E_+=\frac{R-1}{\lambda_+-1}\frac{R-\lambda_-}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-}$$
$$E_-=\frac{R-1}{\lambda_--1}\frac{R-\lambda_+}{\lambda_--\lambda_+}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P(a,b,c)$ be the $n\times n$ matrix where 
$$
 P(a,b,c)_{ij} = \begin{cases}
  a & \text{ if } i,j < n \\
  b & \text{ if } i < n \text{ and } j = n \\
  b & \text{ if } i = n \text{ and } j < n \\
  c & \text{ if } i = j = n.
 \end{cases}
$$

If I understand correctly, you want the square root of $I+P(r,r,0)$.  You can check that 
$$ (I+P(a,b,c))^2 = I + P((n-1)a^2+b^2+2a,(n-1)ab+bc+2b,(n-1)b^2+c^2+2c). $$
Thus, you just need to solve
\begin{align*}
 (n-1)a^2+b^2+2a &= r \\\\
 (n-1)ab+bc+2b &= r \\\\
 (n-1)b^2+c^2+2c &= 0.
\end{align*}
Maple tells me that if we put 
\begin{align*}
 p &= \sqrt{1+(n-1)(r-r^2)} \\\\
 q &= \sqrt{\frac{2p+2+(n-1)r}{(n-1)(n+3)}}
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
 a &= q + \frac{q-r-pq}{(n-1)r} \\\\
 b &= q \\\\
 c &= \frac{q-r-pq}{r}.
\end{align*}

UPDATE:

The square root of $I+P(r,r,r-1)$ can be done similarly.  If we put 
\begin{align*}
 s &= (1 - 2\sqrt{r} + nr)^{-1/2} \\\\
 a &= rs + \frac{s - \sqrt{r}s - 1}{n-1} \\\\
 b &= rs \\\\
 c &= rs - \sqrt{r}s - 1
\end{align*}
then 
$$ \sqrt{I + P(r,r,r-1)} = 1 + P(a,b,c). $$

Comment: I think the OP wants a square root of $I+P(r,r,r-1)$, not $I+P(r,r,0)$.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in $I+P(r,r,r−1)$. Would this approach work for that case as well? (Unfortunately I am not a maple user).

Comment: @unknown: I don't know. But what I sketched in my comment to your question above gives you the solution anyway. The point is that whenever the minimal polynomial factors without multiplicities, as in your case: $(R-1)(R-\lambda_+)(R-\lambda_-)=0$, then one has explicit formulas (which I have now added) for the eigenprojectors and hence a square root. 